# Use istringstream without #include <sstream>

Tags: c++

In class I've been tasked at writing a method for an already defined class, and cannot change class definitions, header files, or #include statements.

I need to split a string into different variables using this code,

```
istringstream ss(line)
ss >> plu >> descp >> one >> price >> weight
```

How can I use istringstream when I cannot use #include < sstream>? Is there a way in c++ to directly call that method instead of #including it in the definitions?

I've tried,

```
istringstream::istringstream ss(line)
std::istringttream:istringstreeam ss(line)
std::istringstream ss(line)
```

And none of those compiled, I don't really know how including files works in C++.

Comment: That seems like a totally arbitrary restriction.  The correct solution is to include `<sstream>` and because it really *is* the right way to do it, I doubt there's a good workaround.  I'm curious to see what people say, though!

Comment: Yes, you should go ask for clarification from your instructor.

Comment: What are `plu`, `descp`, `one`... etc?

Comment: plu, descp, one.. are all primitive values, integers or doubles that line has that I want to parse into plu, descp, one,... The question is focusing more around istringstream.

Comment: It looks as if you're expected to write your own `istringstream` class.

Comment: You **cannot** use `std::istringstream` without (directly or indirectly) including `<sstream>`. Period. There is no possible way. So either an existing header includes `<sstream>` or the `istringstream` you're meant to use is not `std::istringstream`, or you've misunderstood and you're allowed to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: Have fun parsing it manually (and correctly ...).

Comment: What do you mean by indirectly using <sstream>? Through another file's header definitions? If that's the right term?

Comment: I think you are getting the question wrong. That the requirement says 'Don't change include files' doesn't mean you don't include files.

Comment: @Beta, I thought that for a second too but writing istringstream is a pretty daunting task for an intro to c++ class.

Comment: They just want you to write friend functions to the `istringstream` class. Can you do that?

Comment: Nope, I'm only allowed to define one function. checkout() in this case. I don't have the ability to change anything else besides that in the .cpp or .h file.

Comment: You'd better now get one of your class mates (preferably a gf) on the phone to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use istringstream when I cannot use #include < sstream>? Is there a way in c++ to directly call that method instead of #including it in the definitions?

Without copy and pasting the declaration of the `std::istringstream` class from the `<sstream>` header file into your file there's no way the compiler can know how much size to allocate for `ss`. So I'd say: no, there's no easy workaround.

Comment: Would be awesome for compilation times if we could just forgo the headers! (sigh... ) I could use boost everywhere without hesitation..

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I use istringstream when I cannot use `#include <sstream>` ?*

You can not.

> *Is there a way in c++ to directly call that method instead of #including it in the definitions?*

If the definitions are not available, the compiler will not know what to do. It will not even know that the keywords that you are using refer to some types... `istringstream` will be an undefined identifier.